# clEnqueueNDRangeKernel with work dimension=2

Tags: c, linux, parallel-processing, opencl, gpgpu

I am writing a code to add two matrices of dimension 1024*1024 each. 
So my work dimension has to be 2 and the global work size shall be 1024*1024. I want to set the size of each work group to 64*64. How do I achieve that?

So my code should be something like:-

```
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(cl_command_queue command_queue,cl_kernel kernel,cl_uint work_dim,const size_t *global_work_offset,
                       const size_t *global_work_size,const size_t *local_work_size,
                       cl_uint num_events_in_wait_list,const cl_event *event_wait_list,cl_event *event)
```

where `local_work_size=64*64`, `global_work_size=1024*1024`, `work_dim=2`.
How do I obtain individual elements in my kernel code?

This is my kernel code:-

```
__kernel void hello(__global int ** A,__global int ** B,__global int ** C)
{
      int x = get_global_id(0);
     int y = get_global_id(1);
    C[x][y]=A[x][y]+B[x][y];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your kernel launch would look like this:

```
size_t global[2] = {1024, 1024};
size_t local[2]  = {64, 64};
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 2, NULL, global, local, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

and your kernel would retrieve its indices like this:

```
kernel void foo(...)
{
  int x = get_global_id(0);
  int y = get_global_id(1);
  ...
}
```

As an aside, most OpenCL devices that I've come across have a maximum work-group size of 1024, which would mean that they wouldn't support a work-group size of 64x64.

---

Since you can only use 1D buffers in OpenCL, you need to compute your linear array indices manually. Here's how your simple matrix addition kernel would look:

```
__kernel void hello(__global int *A,__global int *B,__global int *C, int width)
{
  int x = get_global_id(0);
  int y = get_global_id(1);
  int index = x + y*width;
  C[index] = A[index] + B[index];
}
```

Comment: If I left the local size blank 
(NULL), will there be any problem?

Comment: @ikk No, unless your kernel assumed the work-group size would be something specific (e.g. if it uses local memory).

Comment: So, then what would be the most efficient work size? If the global size is 1024*1024, then should I set local size as 8*8 considering the local size in most devices is >=64

Comment: 16x16 usually work well for these sorts of things, but this is something that you will likely have to play around with - it won't necessarily be the same for every device, and depends heavily on the kernel too.

Comment: is my kernel code correct @jprice? I am getting error -45!

Comment: Did you check the error code returned by `clBuildProgram`? I imagine the build would have failed, since you cannot use two-dimensional global memory buffers in OpenCL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83103/discussion-between-ikk-and-jprice).

Comment: Is it because the matrix is stored in row major form?

Comment: Yes, my index calculation was assuming you store the data in row major order.